# Почему не работает innerHtml?

Tags: javascript

Вот простенький код для смены текста p-тегов:

```
function fun1() {
    console.log(20);
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    console.log(x);
    x.innerHTML = 'IT is p-elem';
}
```

Это код html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<a id="demo" class="refClass" href="#"></a>

<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<script src="common.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

потому что [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) возвращает **коллекцию** элементов, а у коллекции нет поля *innerHTML*.

Comment: То есть, нужно обращаться через индекс?

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов для обращения к конкретному элементу да

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Не к данному конкретному вопросу, но на всякий случай напомню (прочитал в http://innerhtml.ru/), что вставляемая строка парсится браузером. Поэтому, при некорректной DOM-строке, браузер может вставить совсем не то, что вы ожидаете. Нужно обязательно проверять результат в отладчике,-  сам вот мучился, пропустив кавычку:)