# Почему идет ошибка like.addEventListener is not a function?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код и он работает:

```
function openLikeBlock() {
  var like = document.getElementById("like");
  like.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.classList.contains('open'))
      this.classList.add('open');
    else
      this.classList.remove('open');
  });
}
```

Но если добавить *ClassName* то будет ошибка:

```
var like = document.getElementsByClassName("like");
```

> Uncaught TypeError: like.addEventListener is not a function

Мне нужно именно класс, так как таких блоков несколько на странице (поэтому использую `this`)

Вопрос: как сделать, что бы я мог получать элемент по классу, а не ID?

Comment: уже был **очень** похожий вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532134/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-innerhtml/532135#532135

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Потому что [*getElementsByClassName*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) возвращает **коллекцию** элементов, а у коллекции нет метода [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

для решение можно просто пробежаться по возвращенной коллекции. например так:

```
[].forEach.call(like,function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {...})
});
```

Comment: Добавлю к ответу, что удобнее использовать метод(ы)  [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) /  [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) да и поддержка браузерами получше.

Comment: Спасибо, всегда выручаете)

Comment: @Deonis, `querySelector` - не коллекция :)

Comment: @Other, вы забыли добавить: "*Ваш К.О.*" :D

Comment: @Deonis, Минутка педантичности :)

Comment: Array.from(like, el => el.addEventListener('click', e => {...})); - ES6

Comment: @Deonis, с чего бы у qsa поддержка лучше? Они по другой причине лучше.