# Подскажите как правильно находить элемент в Html, из модуля js?

Tags: javascript

Застрял в одном месте читаю информацию на разных сайтах не могу найти причину такого поведения.

У меня есть html страница которая содержит:

```
<ul class="unordered-list"></ul>
```

в этот список, через js добавляются `li`, из шаблона. Мне необходимо чтобы по клику на одном элементе к данному списку добавлялся класс.

Ментор сказал по id ничего не искать и вообще не вписывать их, поэтому ищу все что нужно по классу.

Написал следующее :

```
    const ul = document.getElementsByClassName('unordered-list');
    console.log(ul);
    ul.classList.add("random-class");
```

в констатне по классу идентифицирую мой список, консоль лог выводит `HTMLCollection [ul.unordered-list]` далее я пытаюсь добавить класс к этому элементу html, получаю ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (main.js:130)`

смущает вот это указание про коллекцию, а не просто строкой код, подозреваю что это какая то глупая ошибка из за непонимания с моей стороны, разъясните этот момент пожалуйста.

Comment: `ul[0].classList.add("random-class");`

Comment: А подскажите или укажите где можно почитать, из за чего необходимо добавлять [0] ? У меня только 1 элемент на странице с классом по которому я ищу.

Это очень интересно, работает как нужно в таком случае:

`const ul = document.getElementsByClassName('unordered-list')[0];`

Comment: @Mark, загугли: Document.getElementsByClassName() MDN.
[MDN - Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName),
[JSLearrn - getElementsBy*](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom#getelementsby)

Comment: @Mark `document.querySelector('.unordered-list').classList.add("random-class");`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему идет ошибка like.addEventListener is not a function?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543392/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-like-addeventlistener-is-not-a-function)