# помогите перевести на нативный Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть код

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("body").on("mouseover", "video", function(){
         this.play();
     });
     $("body").on("mouseleave", "video", function(){
         this.pause();
         this.currentTime = 0;
         // this.load();
     })
 })
```

нужно первести в нативный Js, это так

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

video.onmousemove = function(){
    this.play();
};

video.onmouseout = function(){
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
};
```

суть в том что когда наводишь на видео оно воспроизводится а когда отводишь курсор возвращается в началоб на Jquery работает нормально при любом количестве видео, а на нативном нормально работает только с одним видео...
Подскажите пожалуйства как сделать правильно

Comment: getElement**s**ByTagName - возвращает коллекцию.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не работает innerHtml?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532134/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-innerhtml)

Answer (score 1):

Этот код работает не так как вы думаете

```
 $("body").on("mouseover", "video", function(){
     this.play();
 });
```

`on` добавит листнер не на `video` элементы а на `body` и будет фильтровать все события которые до него "баблятся".

На vanilla js это будет выглядеть так:

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function( ev ){
   if( ev.target.nodeName === 'VIDEO' ){
       ev.target.play()
   }
});
```

Аналогично для `mouseout`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что `getElementsByTagName` возвращает тебе целую **HTMLCollection** со всеми нодами с тэгом `video`.

Как вариант, ты можешь пробегаться по полученной коллекции и каждому ноду добавлять хэндлера на событие.